# Error en angularJS usando CORS - Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403 on angular post request

Tags: angularjs

Estimados,

Tengo este código en angularjs:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/employee/'
    , $scope.alumno
    ,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
    ).success(function(data){

        if ( data.err === false ) {
            $scope.actualizado = true;

            setTimeout(function() {
                $scope.actualizado = false;
                $scope.$apply();
            }, 3500);

        };
    });
```

Mi API tiene estos datos:

```
//Add employee:
Url: http://localhost:8080/employee
Type request: POST
Add a new employee:
{
 "firstName": "Javier",
 "lastName": "Piedra",
}
```

Uso chrome con una extensión que habilita CORS para GET funciona perfecto pero para POST muestra este error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/employee/. Response for 
preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

En mi app.config uso esto:

```
app.config( function($routeProvider,$httpProvider){

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
```

Tienen una solución para este error?

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de investigar bastante puedo confirmar que hacer esta acción por defecto **no se puede** que existen extensiones en [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) por ejemplo que permite realizar el uso de GET pero para POST y PUT ya no.
Lo correcto es realizar el cambio desde la API y de esa forma solucionarlo.